# Non JSR303 equivalent of @Valid annotation in Spring 3.x?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

Plain and simple issue:

- I would like to **annotate my method parameter** with some sort of annotation that would **fire regular spring validation** mechanism (based on `Validator` interface)
- **I don't want** to include JSR303 dependency

Any ideas? I looked on `@Validated` but it seems that it was not created for this purpose.

Right now I do it like this:

```
public String req(@ModelAttribute SomeRequest request, BindingResult errors) {
        validator.validate(request, errors); // This can be avoided
        if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
            // Valid request
            return ...
        } else {
            // There were errors 
            return ...
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use JSR-303?

Comment: I find it strange that using one annotation would require including another dependency. There has to be another way, it's just bugs me out :)

Comment: What's wrong with @Validated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you need to create custom annotation using **@interface** and then use that instead of standard @Valid annotation and at runtime identify it and validate your fields accordingly. Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I would need to involve AOP and do lots of runtime checking. I cannot believe it would be that time consuming. Most of annotations from J2EE specs have equivalents, I'm sure `@Valid `has one too!

Comment: Yes in that case you need to do lots of other stuff like AOP. Other than that there is no option for what you want to achieve. As far as I know there is no other equivalent annotation for @Valid. :-)